# How to add features (attributes) from a CSV file without geometry to a polygon shapefile?

Tags: qgis, shapefile, csv

I would like to add attributes from a CSV file (that's one below ) [image]

to a polygon shapefile layer  (that's one)[image]

in QGIS 2.10.

The problem is they have no corresponding fields which I could use for join.

Comment: If you have no join field, how do you expect to do a join? Please [edit] the question to provide more information.

Comment: How about the countries? Do they identify your values? In the .csv it looks like they might be uniqe. You could then join them to a geometry with country names and finally with a spatial join to your polygons.

Comment: To Vince: I wondering if it's possible and how if is. Maybe some plugin  that allow to add only selected field or something else.

Comment: To Matte: Would you give me example what you mean?